# Working Out Easy Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

does anyone know how to do this equation? I know it's easy but I can't work out what the question means.

[image]

When I expanded the first equation:

$(y+4)-(y-3)$

$y^2 -3y +4y - 12$

$y^2-1y-12$

Not sure what I should do after.

Can someone explain how would you work it out in easy terms?

Thank you

Comment: Aren't the answers just $7$ and $1$ or am I really overlooking something?

Comment: Thank you, another thing. Is there a way of finding out the answer the way I expanded the equation above with $y^2 -7y -12$?

Comment: No need to square any terms. If anything it will just complicate things as well as add the possibility of additional (extraneous) solutions

Comment: In your expansion it looks like you're taking the *product* of $(y+4)$ and $(y-3)$ rather than their *difference* (but also using the subtraction sign to between the two terms to get a $-4y$ instead of a $+4y$ in the expansion).

Comment: Oh ok, I kind of understand the concept now. I'll think I'll do some more revision in subtracting quantities. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you made the jump from $(y+4)-(y-3)$ to $y^2-3y+4y-12$, you were applying the expansion rules for quantities *multiplied* together, not *subtracted*.

Multiplication: $(y+4)(y-3)=y^2-3y+4y-12$

Subtraction: $(y+4)-(y-3)=y+4-y+3  = 7$

Therefore, your answer for the first question above should really be seven.

Answer (score 11):

It might help to look at it like this:

$$\begin{align}
(y+4) & \\
-\quad(y-3) & \\
 & \\
\hline & \\
7
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

$$(y + 4) - (y - 3) = (y + 4) - (y) - (-3) = (y+4) + (3 - y) = (y - y) + (3 + 4) = 7$$

$$(y-2) - (y - 3) = (y - 2) - y - (-3) = (y-2) + (3 - y) = (y - y) + (3 - 2) = 1$$

In general,

$$(y-a) - (y - b) = b - a$$

In the same way that $x + (y + z) = x + y + z$, $x - (y + z) = x - y - z$. The minus sign distributes to all terms and reverses their sign. Mainly because 
$$z - (x + y) = z + (-1)(x + y) = z + (-1)x + (-1)y = z - x - y$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that, for any numbers $a$ and $b$, we have that 
$$
-(a-b)=(-1)(a-b)=(-1)(a)-(-1)(b)=-a-(-b)=-a+b=b-a.
$$
Use this observation for your problems below.

---

**Problem 1:** What is $(y+4)-(y-3)$?

*Answer.* We have that
$$
(y+4)-(y-3)=y+4-y+3=7.
$$

**Problem 2:** What is $(y-2)-(y-3)$?

*Answer.* We have that
$$
(y-2)-(y-3)=y-2-y+3=1.
$$

---

If you make sure to use the observation given at the beginning of the answer, the above calculations should make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, by this you can understnad : 
$(y+4)-(y-3)=(y+4)+[-(y-3)]=y+4+[-y+3]=y+4-y+3=7$.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

1. Distribute the central minus sign:
   $$
   (y+3)-(y-2)=5 \hspace{5mm} \Rightarrow \hspace{5mm} (y+3)+(-y+2)
   $$
2. Drop the parentheses:
   $$
   (y+3)+(-y+2) \hspace{5mm} \Rightarrow \hspace{5mm} y+3-y+2
   $$
3. Cancel the variables:
   $$
   y+3-y+2 \hspace{5mm} \Rightarrow \hspace{5mm} 3+2
   $$
4. I think you've got it from here. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

What you did incorrectly is that you mistook the expression to say $(y+4)(y+3)$ because you expanded to turn it into a quadratic.

The expression is actually a difference so what you should get is:

$(y+4)-(y-3)=y+4-y+3=7$

and

$(y-2)-(y-3)=y-2-y+3=1$

Answer (score -1):

First do (y + 4) - (y - 3)

= y + 4 - y + 3

= 7

Then do (y - 2) - (y - 3)

= y - 2 - y + 3

= 1

Comment: When the question confuses the OP, this is not going to help.

Answer (score -2):

This is an identity, not an equation. It is true for any real number y. Hence you can't solve the equation to get a single number.

Comment: The blanks can indeed be filled in with numbers, that do not depend on any specific value of $y$. So I'm not terribly clear what your answer is addressing. Cleaned up, this would make a better comment than an answer.